# Ant possible to insert cmd line input key-value pairs to match a property file?

Tags: ant, key-value

I have a property file includes key-value pairs:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
...
```

I have an Ant target called "compute". I would like to override the values by referring to the key like this:

```
ant compute -Dkey1=this is my value
```

How would this be possible to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ant compute -Dkey1="this is my value"
```

There are many ways to achieve this (Asking for user input with `<input/>` task, setting the var in the Global Properties (under Preferences->Ant), etc), but i know only those on Eclipse :S

By the way, if what you want is to change multiple variables-per-setting (like environments settings), you can use different property files, like dev.properties, test.properties and prod.properties, and then hard-code the variable values into those files.

Then you will only need ONE parameter at the beginning, specifying which "set" (file) of variables you wanna pick... 
And your parameter will not override any other, it will be straight in the command line, like

```
ant compute -Denv="test"
or
ant compute -Denv=test
```

, that must work (unless Ant guide is wrong, and i don't think so).

Comment: Does it work if you comment the property file ? Sorry but i use ANT from Eclipse, not command line, but your code seems right according to Apache guide...

Comment: didn't seem to help. The only solution so far that I have found is that the default value would be e.g. @value1@ and then one can replace it, but I would like it to have a sensible default value from the start